# Error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when blending and pasting an image on other Image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was getting the error on the line `blk_img[y_offset:y_end,x_offset:x_end] = int(resz_PerspctvTransformed).`

I am trying to paste the image `resz_PerspctvTransformed` on a black background. Trying to implement the code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
counter = 0
cordnts = np.zeros((4,2),dtype=int)

# Function definition
def mouseClickFun(event,x,y,flag,params):
    global counter
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if counter<=3 :
            cordnts[counter]= x,y
            counter=counter+1

img1 = cv2.imread('D:\\Project Code\\Input_img\\img_2.jpg',1)

print('Original Dimensions: ',img1.shape)
resz_image = cv2.resize(img1,None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3, interpolation= cv2.INTER_AREA) 
print('Resized Dimenstion',resz_image.shape)

width,height= 400, 600
wBG,hBG=600,600
blk_img=np.zeros((wBG,hBG,3),dtype=int)

while True:
    for x in range(0,4):
        cv2.circle(resz_image,(cordnts[x,0],cordnts[x,1]),2,[0,255,255],2)

    cv2.imshow("Resized_Image",resz_image)  
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Resized_Image",mouseClickFun)
    basePnt=width/3

    x_offset = int((wBG/4))
    y_offset = 0 #Chnged to 0 from (wBG/4)
    x_end = int((x_offset + ((wBG/4)*2)))
    y_end = int((y_offset + ((hBG/4)*2)))

    if counter == 4:
        pnt1 = np.float32([cordnts[0],cordnts[1],cordnts[2],cordnts[3]])
        pnt2 = np.float32([[0,0], [width,0], [basePnt,height], [(basePnt*2),height]])
        PerspectiveMatrix= cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pnt1,pnt2)
        img_PerspctvTransformed= cv2.warpPerspective(resz_image,PerspectiveMatrix,(width,height))
        resz_PerspctvTransformed = cv2.resize(img_PerspctvTransformed,(300,300), interpolation= cv2.INTER_AREA) 
        cv2.imshow("resized Img",resz_PerspctvTransformed)
        blk_img[y_offset:y_end,x_offset:x_end] = int(resz_PerspctvTransformed)
        cv2.imshow("Background Img",blk_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        break

    cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `int()` is python function that works with just one number, not an array of them.  Did you look it up or test it after hitting this error?

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to be the error I guess. Moreover I removed it later on as int() seems to be working only on single value only. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.
First, whenever you create an image or set an image type, make sure it is the correct type. You have created the image `blk_img` of type `int` that is of 32-bit size whereas an image can have integer values in the range of 0-255, that is, the image should be of the type `np.uint8` (unsigned int 8). Thus, correct line 22 as:

```
blk_img=np.zeros((wBG,hBG,3),dtype=np.uint8)
```

Second of all, if you want to convert the image to an integer type, `int(image_name)` is not the correct syntax. Instead, use the code below:

```
blk_img[y_offset:y_end,x_offset:x_end] = np.asarray(resz_PerspctvTransformed, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Moreover, you do not need to worry about the data type of the `resz_PerspctvTransformed` image as it is already integer type.

Comment: That very well solves the problem that I was facing. Thanks a lot for your suggestion Rahul.

Comment: No problem, mark this question as answered if it is done.